# Google Closure Compiler: remove dead code by setting CompilerOptions

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, google-closure-compiler

I am trying to configure the CompilerOptions of Google Closure Compiler by setting corresponding fields. However, when I call the method setRemoveDeadCode() to activate the dead code removal in simple mode, only a warning "unreachable code" is reported and the dead code is not removed. Why is that?

The code is like following:

```
if (false) console.log(x);  //dead code which should be removed
```

What I do is only activate the setRemoveDeadCode() at the end of the method createOptions(), but deactivate other options. Doing the same thing on other options like setCoalesceVariableNames() works fine. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RemoveDeadCode` option triggers a pass that looks at side-effects and the control-flow-graph.  You can see what it does by looking at the unit tests:

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/a1488d59c11fd535ded79d37c11cd418927782ce/test/com/google/javascript/jscomp/UnreachableCodeEliminationTest.java

It doesn't look for constant values.  There is another option however, "Fold Constants" (via `setFoldConstants`) that will remove the `if` with a constant condition.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I figured it out about their effects on compilation optimizations.